# Horizontal scrolling containing multiple draggable lists in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, draggable

I'm creating an app with an intended layout being a series of column lists with the ability to drag a list item from one column to another. Additionally the entire layout should be horizontally scrollable (as the number of columns are generated dynamically). I would like to know the best way to do this on Android. [Imagine how JIRA's agile board is laid out](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/files/715359130/716734598/1/1424864317248/JIRA6.4_Kanbanview.png).

My understanding is having list/recyclerviews in a horizontal scroll view is a big no-no, so I thought about GridLayout but I would like the lists to be independently vertically scrollable as well as the layout as whole should be able to be scrolled horizontally.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) check this

Answer (score 1):

Think about using nested RecyclerViews. Lets say, your Layout contains a RecyclerView that gets horizontally(set the LinearLayoutManager to populate it to your preferred orientation) populated with other recyclerViews (your Columns). Each child-row is a recyclerView that gets populated by a second Adapter.

Comment: Cool, so that solves one part of the problem thanks! Any idea about the best ways to implement a way to drag items from one recycler view to another? I can do it for the same recycler, but not quite sure where to go from there.